# How to find, iterate and update documents in one run in mongo collection?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I need to find certain documents in the collection (Event), then loop through them and alter a part of the data in each document, and then update these documents in the collection. Here's my code:

```
    Event.find({linkId: linkId}).then(
        docs => {
            docs.forEach((doc) => {
                newTitle = doc.title.split('-')[0] + ' - ' + eventDuration + ' days';
                console.log(newTitle);
                Event.update({_id: doc._id}, {title: newTitle});
            })
        }
    );
```

Console shows that I receive a title for each required document and modify it as needed, however, the modified data is not inserted back into the collection.
Any help is very much appreciated.
Thank you
================================================================
Part 2. More information
This is part of interactive schedule web app, which is based on "fullcalendar" package. There are two parts on the web calendar - Project and Personnel. User creates new event in the Project part and this creates two docs in mongo DB (scheme is below).
Event scheme:

```
eventSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
id: {
    type    : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    default : mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
    index   : { unique: true }
  },
title: String,
start: Date,
end: Date,
linkId: String});
```

These two docs have identical start/end dates, linkID, but different titles. JS creates title depending on where the event is rendered: in Project part it's "Person name - XY days", and in Personnel part it's "Project name - XY days", where XY = endDate - startDate. User is able to resize events dynamically in the calendar that updates corresponding docs in DB. Updating dates is not a problem but altering the titles is a bit more complicated. Initially, I used the code below, but then found out that using `updateMany` method makes both titles identical, i.e. if the user resizes an event in the Project calendar part, both titles become "Person name - XY days", and if in the Personnel part - titles turn to "Project name - XY days". And so what I want to achieve now is when a user resizes an event in the calendar, JS finds corresponding two docs in DB using linkID, loops through them, updates dates, and updates only XY in titles based on new event duration. Hope I got an idea across). Thank you in advance

```
var result = req.body,
    startDate = new Date(result.newStartDate),
    newStartDate = startDate.setUTCHours(12),
    endDate = new Date(result.newEndDate),
    newEndDate = endDate.setUTCHours(12),
    linkId = result.linkId,
    title = result.title,
    trimmedTitle = originalTitle.split('-')[0],
    eventDuration = ((newEndDate - newStartDate) / 86400000) + 1;
    newTitle = trimmedTitle + '- ' + eventDuration + ' days';
Event.updateMany({linkId: linkId}, {start: newStartDate, end: newEndDate, title: newTitle};
```

Comment: Not sure about all the mongodb methods in javascript (I'm more familiar with those in studio 3t), but instead of calling update, if you `doc.title = ... new title value ...` you should then be able to `Event.save(doc)`, if the javascript implementation of mongodb has the save call; which I would hope it would.

Comment: Otherwise try `Event.update({ _id: doc._id }, { $set: { title: newTitle } })`

Comment: Post a sample input document and the expected output document (or its fields).

Comment: @Taplar Thank you for your reply. I tried `$set` but got no result. Tried `Event.save` in two ways: `doc.title = newTitle; Event.save(doc)` and `Event.save({_id: doc._id, title: newTitle});` in both cases got error `TypeError: Event.save is not a function`

Comment: @prasad_  Thank you for your reply. I added some color in part 2.

Comment: What about `Event.update(doc)`?

Comment: @Taplar Tried `Event.update(doc)` - in vain :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. Instead of using `collection.save.(doc)` or `collection.update(doc)` I used `collection.create(doc)`and it works. Finally, the code looks like this:

```
Event.find({linkId: linkId}).exec((err, docs) => {
        docs.forEach(doc => {
            doc.start = startDate;
            doc.end = endDate;
            doc.duration = eventDuration;
            oldTitle = doc.title;
            doc.title = oldTitle.split('-')[0] + ' - ' + eventDuration + ' days';
            Event.create(doc, (err)=>{
                if(err){
                    console.log(err);
                };
            });
        });
    });
```